# change form element by name element with jquery

Tags: jquery, forms

I need to select and change a hidden element inside a form with jquery but I'm not sure how exactly.

```
<form id="dologinform" method="post" action="loginservice.ashx">
<input type="text" name="username" />
<input type="text" name="password" />
<input type="hidden" name="redirect_page" />
</form>
```

I need to alter the redirect page using jquery but the following code is not working...

```
var newURL = "altloginservice.aspx";
$('#dologinform input[name=redirect_page]').val(newURL);
```

I want to select the element by name and not position in order to future proof the code in case the order of the tags changes etc...

Comment: looks good to me, what problem are you experiencing? Even checke dit using jsfiddle - works fine: http://jsfiddle.net/U87JY/

Comment: Is the code within a `$(document).ready` block? Technically, inverted commas `"` are required around the value in the attribute equals selector, so you might try `name="redirect_page"`, though it shouldn't make a difference.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the attribute "equals" selector you are after is `"="` like you had it but the value needs to be in `""` if you use `''` on the outside, or enclosed in `''` if you use `""` on the outside

```
$("#dologinform input[name='redirect_page']").val(newURL);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var newURL = "altloginservice.aspx";

$("#dologinform input[name=redirect_page]").attr("action", newURL);
```

Answer (score 0):

From jquery [documentation](http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/attribute-selectors/): attribute values in selector expressions must be surrounded by quotation marks.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure to put the name between quotes:

```
$("#dologinform input[name='redirect_page']").val(newURL);
```